# Purpose of Phase Angle Image

Tags: image-processing, fft, dft

I am learning Fourier Transform from many days but till now I am not able to understand what does phase angle image show us or tell us? They say that  MAGNITUDE tells "how much" of a certain frequency component is present and the PHASE tells "where" the frequency component is in the image. I understood about the MAGNITUDE part but not able to understand PHASE part. Please explain what it means by "PHASE  tells "where" the frequency component is in the image". Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming question - you'll probably get a better response if you ask on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank You Paul for guiding me.

Comment: Think of the difference between a graph of a sine and a cosine. The difference is the phase, it's a shift of position.